# operator overloading and polymorphism difference

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, overloading

I know parameter overloading and polymorphism are not the same. Basically, polymorphism allows different behaviour based on the object type. So, in a sense , is operator overloading not a manifestation of polymorphism ?

For example, + can be used to add two ints, and I can also use it to add two class member variables, also of type int.

Comment: Yes, operator (and function) overloading is one way of implementing polymorphism.

Comment: Does it really matter? It's just a word.

Comment: No @KerrekSB, it is not only a word. Behind the word there is a concept, and polymorphism is a very important thing to consider when writing code.

Comment: There's no polymorphism in your example since you're adding two ints in both cases.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès answer was very good but if you are still confused or want another example look at this answer on codeguru: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?517296-difference-between-polymorphism-and-overloading#2

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Meh. There's only so much you can get out of developing taxonomies. What matters is that you know how to write good code (usable, reusable, maintanable, efficient). You may need overloading, specializing, inheriting, templating or overriding, but it's far more important to know how each of those fit than to give them some arbitrary, heavily overloaded name. Taxonomy helps when it establishes a common vocabulary, but in this case everybody is going to come up with something slightly different but similar sounding, which I doubt will be useful.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't believe that you can really manage something that you cannot name. As you said, if you are doing overriding, it should be better to know that it is called overriding, if not how would you talk about it with others? This is exactly why he asked for it! He wanted to know what he was really doing. Now he probably understand polymorphism much better...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès You just say "operator overloading" and it is clearer than "Type 42 polymorphism" or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes operator overloading is also polymorphism.

In fact there is three kind of polymorphism :

- overloading implements what is called *ad-hoc* polymorphism
- subtyping implements the inclusion polymorphism
- genericity implements parametric polymorphism.

The *ad-hoc* polymorphism is commonly considered not to be very powerful, it is only convenient.

Comment: In my world, "ad-hoc polymorphism" refers to type erasure a la `boost::any`... but each to their own :-)

Comment: http://www.techopedia.com/definition/17481/ad-hoc-polymorphism, http://homepages.feis.herts.ac.uk/~msc_fl/fl-node60.html

Comment: Apparently, one interviewer said function overloading as applied to functions with the same name but different parameters does not constitute polymorphism :/ meh. Would you agree?

Comment: No, **it is polymorphism**. It is a "syntactic polymorphism", a static polymorphism solved at compile time. An expression compiled differently depending on types or number of args. Polymorphism is too frequently associated to dynamic polymorphism, the one that occurs at runtime, but polymorphism is just the capacity to react differently to some conditions. C++ templates are statically solved and nobody will tell you that it is not polymorphism (some may say that templates are bad).

Comment: For example in Java `println()` is polymorphic, even if it is in fact a collection of different functions, as a user you don't mind, it is polymorphic, it behave differently depending on the parameter! The way it is implemented is not relevant to our discussion! By the way, polymorphism is just an illusion, because at the end a single function is chosen, so either at compile-time or at run-time makes no difference.